# Get the top-left most point from random points

Tags: geometry, fixed-points

For each word in the picture shown below, there is a point that represents the top-left point $(x, y)$ of the rectangle.

How would you find which point is at the most top-left of the page given a random set of points?

In other words, how do you sort a random set of points like this to create the correct English sentence order?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This problem is not really mathematically well-defined. "Jan" sits to the right of but above "However" -- does that make it "top left"? When reading a sentence we give priority to the "top", so that would put "Jan" before "However", which is clearly not how the sentence is meant to be read.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to find the corner that minimizes $x+my$ (assuming a top-down $y$ axis), where $m$ is a well-chosen slope parameter. The green line is the locus of $x+my=\text{Cst}$, it must intersect a single box.

[image]